# Average Rate of Change Related to distance and angle

Tags: calculus

I am supposed to find the Ave Rate of Change related to the distance from a satellite to the surface of the earth.

$r=3960$ miles

$h = r(\csc(θ) − 1)$

When $θ$ changes from $\pi/4$ to $\pi/3$

Have I set this up correctly?

$$ \frac {f(3960(\csc(\pi/4) − 1) − f(3960(\csc(\pi/3)− 1)}{\pi/4−\pi/3} $$

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Formula for average rate is "change in function value / change in input value" where change is final minus initial.